# Quill.js: Making custom link formats -or- Custom formats with the same tag name

Tags: quill

I'm using Quill `1.0.0-rc.1`. How can I make several different types of link formats?  I've made three different types of link formats that add a `data-link-type` attribute.  When I create the links, it's fine.  However, when I reload the content into the editor using `pasteHTML`, the last registered format wins since the `tagName`s are all 'A', and so all the `data-link-type`s get set to `resource`.

So this:

```
<p>These are the links: 
  <a href="http://www.google.com" data-link-type="external">External</a> 
  <a href="/resources/3" data-link-type="resource">Resource</a>
  <a href="/pages/12" data-link-type="internal">Internal</a>
</p>
```

Becomes this:

```
<p>These are the links: 
  <a href="http://www.google.com" data-link-type="resource">External</a> 
  <a href="/resources/3" data-link-type="resource">Resource</a>
  <a href="/pages/12" data-link-type="resource">Internal</a>
</p>
```

I've included a code pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akxNNK

```js
var Inline = Quill.import('blots/inline');

class ExternalLink extends Inline {
  static create(value) {
    let node = super.create(value);
    value = value.trim();
    if (!value.match(/^http|mailto/)) {
      value = 'http://' + value
    }
    node.setAttribute('href', value);
    node.setAttribute('data-link-type', 'external');
    return node;
  }

  static formats(domNode) {
    return domNode.getAttribute('href');
  }
}

ExternalLink.blotName = 'external_link';
ExternalLink.tagName = 'A';


class InternalLink extends Inline {
  static create(value) {
    let node = super.create(value);
    if (!value.match(/^\/pages\//)) {
      value = '/pages/' + value
    }
    node.setAttribute('href', value);
    node.setAttribute('data-link-type', 'internal');
    return node;
  }

  static formats(domNode) {
    return domNode.getAttribute('href');
  }
}

InternalLink.blotName = 'internal_link';
InternalLink.tagName = 'A';


class ResourceLink extends Inline {
  static create(value) {
    let node = super.create(value);
    if (!value.match(/^\/resources\//)) {
      value = '/resources/' + value
    }
    node.setAttribute('href', value);
    node.setAttribute('data-link-type', 'resource');
    return node;
  }

  static formats(domNode) {
    return domNode.getAttribute('href');
  }
}

ResourceLink.blotName = 'resource_link';
ResourceLink.tagName = 'A';


Quill.register({
  'formats/internal_link': InternalLink,
  'formats/external_link': ExternalLink,
  'formats/resource_link': ResourceLink
});


var quill = new Quill(
  '#editor-container',
  { theme: 'snow' }
);

quill.pasteHTML('<p>These are the links: <a href="http://www.google.com" data-link-type="external">External</a> <a href="/resources/3" data-link-type="resource">Resource</a> <a href="/pages/12" data-link-type="internal">Internal</a></p>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quill can use `tagName` and/or `className` to map DOM nodes to its document model. Simply setting an attribute in `create` is not sufficient. This is intentional to allow extraneous attributes like `target` or `rel` to be set without that do not contribute meaningful content to the document (if an attribute was meaningful, then you would use an [Attributor](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment#attributors)).

This forked [CodePen](http://codepen.io/quill/pen/VjNaEw) has your example working with className. Note when no classname is present, it will use the tagName, which depends on registration order.