# Quill.js keeps stripping classes from anchor tags

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, quill

I've written a custom link module to handle internal links, etc. Also the module adds some classes to the A tags, so they can be displayed differently.
But Quill removes the classes once it gets instantiated again.

I've already found out that you need a custom attributor. But I can not get it working.
To keep thinks simple, I've created [a sandbox (without my module)](https://codesandbox.io/s/quill-removes-classes-from-anchor-tags-trz9b?file=/index.js).

Here is the code:

```html
<!-- ... -->
<div id="editor">
  <a href="/test" class="btn">Foo</a>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

```js
import Quill from "quill";
import "quill-paste-smart";

import "quill/dist/quill.snow.css";

const Parchment = Quill.import("parchment");

let LinkClass = new Parchment.Attributor.Class("link", "ql-link", {
  scope: Parchment.Scope.INLINE,
  whitelist: ["btn"]
});
Quill.register({ "attributors/class/link": LinkClass }, true);

new Quill("#editor", {
  theme: "snow",
  modules: {
    toolbar: ["bold", "italic", "underline", "link", "clean"]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add that element in side of your Quill instance as well, using the `Inline` class.

Here is an example:

```js
const Inline = Quill.import("blots/inline");


InternalLink.blotName = "internal_link";
InternalLink.className = "btn";
InternalLink.tagName = "A";

Quill.register({
  "attributors/class/link": LinkClass,
  "formats/internal_link": InternalLink
});
```

[image: Edit Quill removes classes from anchor tags (forked)]

I didn't think the documentation was helpful but here is an example that can help also:

- [Quill.js: Making custom link formats -or- Custom formats with the same tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027255/quill-js-making-custom-link-formats-or-custom-formats-with-the-same-tag-name)

Comment: Nice. Thank You. I started to lose hope :)

Comment: Maybe you can also tell, how to allow multiple classes? `InternalLink.className` does not take an array.

Comment: @GordonFreeman if you ask another question and tag me on it, I'll look in to it.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the accepted answer does not fully solve my issue.
I was looking for a possible way to add/keep *multiple* classes.

Here is the final solution:

```js
const Inline = Quill.import("blots/inline");

const ATTRIBUTES = ["href", "rel", "target", "class"];
class InternalLink extends Inline {
  static create(value) {
    let node = super.create(value);
    node.setAttribute("href", value.href);
    if (value.rel) node.setAttribute("rel", value.rel);
    if (value.target) node.setAttribute("target", value.target);
    if (value.class) node.setAttribute("class", value.class);
    return node;
  }

  static formats(domNode) {
    return ATTRIBUTES.reduce((formats, attribute) => {
      if (domNode.hasAttribute(attribute)) {
        formats[attribute] = domNode.getAttribute(attribute);
      }
      return formats;
    }, {});
  }
}

InternalLink.blotName = "internal_link";
InternalLink.tagName = "A";

Quill.register({
  "formats/link": InternalLink
});
```

[image: Edit Quill removes classes from anchor tags (forked)]

Comment: Thank you SO much. I dropped an [alternate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76221306/802469) that keeps all attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of [Gordon's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64843465/802469).

This version will keep all attributes (in my preliminary testing) & doesn't require them to be explicitly defined the blot.

```js
const Inline = Quill.import("blots/inline");

class FixedLink extends Inline {
    static create(value) {
        let node = super.create(value);
        for (const key in value){
            node.setAttribute(key, value[key]);
        }
        return node;
    }

    static formats(domNode) {
        const attributes = {};
        for (const attr of domNode.attributes){
            attributes[attr.name] = attr.value;
        }
        return attributes;
    }
}

FixedLink.blotName = "fixed_link";
FixedLink.tagName = "A";
```